# open a custom dialog when custom listview item Edittext is clicked

Tags: android

I want to open a Custom Dialog() when my Custom list view item is clicked.

I tried so far but can't open the dialog. Here is code details:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.input_dialog);
    dialog.setTitle("What about Today!");

           **//initialize custom dialog items.**
    EditText mood = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextyourMode);
    Button btnSaveButton = (Button) dialog
            .findViewById(R.id.btnSaveMyMoods);
    Button btnClear = (Button) dialog
            .findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
    dialog.show();

}
```

here is custom Array adapter getView(...) method.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sell_info_list, parent, false);


TextView product_id = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.product_id);//
product_id.setText(products.get(position).getProduct_id());

EditText product_quantity = (EditText) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.editTextQuantity);

return rowView;
}
```

Finally,I want to open this dialog whenList view item edit text is clicked.
Anyone help me?

Comment: you should set OnClickListener at "product_quantity" inside the getView() method and do your work there.

Comment: @Carnal :thanks for interacting.i tried your way.My target is to set Text on List view Edit box from custom dialog Box edit text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i open the dialog typing from these inside getView(...) in Adapter and also can showing on the selected listview item EditText.

```
    rowView.setClickable(true);
    rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.input_dialog);
            dialog.setTitle("What about Today!");

            final EditText txtMode = (EditText) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.editTextyourMode);
            Button btnSave = (Button) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.btnSaveMyMoods);

            btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String data = txtMode.getText().toString();
                    product_quantity.setText(data);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Log.d("data", data);

                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Then the Screen look like that.
[image]

**Now facing a problem.My List View has just 10 items.When i scrolling the list view,the item text vanish which is unseen**

Thanks every one for sharing knowledge.**

Comment: This the issue of recycling list view so on dismiss the dialog please store edit box text in ArrayList or any other data. please also write code using the view holder.

Comment: where does context come from ont his?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I didnt see you were using a CustomAdapter, do this in the adapter

```
rowView.setClickable(true);
    rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View paramView)
                    {
                      //if you want you can use the "position" value to get the desired row items.
                    }
                    });
```

Comment: :Thanks it works fine. But now i wanna set text to edittext from Dialog box Editext Inputs. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thankyou... Have fun coding!!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
// Click event for single list row
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
                EditText edit = (EditText) (findViewById(R.id.editText));
                if (edit != null) {
                    edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CLICKED",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "EditText not found",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

set an onclick listener on your edit text and if it doesn't pop any dialog try setting the settings of your edittext android:focusable = "false" that is if u already put an listener on your edit text and still nothing happens

Comment: android:focusable = "false" works to select only list view item. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Adpter write this code

```
EditText product_quantity = (EditText) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.editTextQuantity);
        product_quantity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.input_dialog);
                dialog.setTitle("What about Today!");

                //initialize custom dialog items.**
                EditText mood = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextyourMode);
                Button btnSaveButton = (Button) dialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.btnSaveMyMoods);
                Button btnClear = (Button) dialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
                dialog.show();

            }
        });
```